# Add rows based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with Excel vba coding for an Excel file that im working on.

I want to code something in vba so it adds rows to the active sheet based on cell value.
For example- If cell value (c14 value is 10) VBA adds 10 rows after C2 row when clicked on Add rows button.

If the cell value (C14 is 15 it adds 15 rows after C2 row).

Want to copy formatting from C2 row when adding the rows (copy formatting from c2 row to the new rows.

Also, I did one email vba which copies range and paste that range into an email.

What VBA coding I can add so that when 10 or 15 new rows are added the selection of the range to copy adjusts automatically.

Right now if I manually insert 10 rows vba is copying `Range("C2:C27")` 
it wont adjust to copy `Range("C2:C37")`

Answer (score 0):

this will help

```
Dim rowsToAdd as Integer
rowsToAdd = Range("C14").Value

Rows("2:2").Copy
Rows("3:3").Resize(rowsToAdd).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```